# How to unset baseURL in axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have set baseURL in other part of the code, and I would not use that one.

In thought if I set it to `window.location.host`, it will override, unset it. But not.

```js
axios
    .create({
            baseURL: window.location.host,
    })
    .get('/api/generatePostAnimation', {
```

I see two times in the `Request URL` the host `tikex-dev.com`. Why?

[image]

Comment: `host` is not the full URL, try `window.location.href`

Comment: or use `window.location.origin`

Answer (score 0):

Using interceptors of the Axios: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: window.location.host,
});
instance.interceptors.request.use(req => {
   // You can check path url '/api/generatePostAnimation' too
   req.url = 'yourNewBaseUrl',
});
```

Comment: I do not get. You use the same as me.

Comment: Basically, using inteceptors you can change baseURL any request. But your instance already correct. But you should set baseUrl using location.origin (not location.host)